# Matplotlib transData.transform, ValueError: object too deep for desired array when applied to date

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to update a scatter plot with set_offsets().  My x-axis is defined by a date.  I believe I need to use ax.transData.transform() to get the offset values.  This seems to work fine for floats but when using a date, I get an error ValueError: object too deep for desired array.

```
from datetime import date

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = [date(2010,5,14), date(2013,2,3), date(2014,10,9)]
y = [0.3, 0.5, 0.7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(date(2010, 1, 1), date(2015, 1, 1))
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y)

offsets = scatter.get_offsets()
new_offsets = np.array(ax.transData.transform([[date(2011,3,4), .6],[date(2012,3,4),.7]]))
new_offsets = np.append(offsets, new_offset, axis=0)

scatter.set_offsets(new_offsets)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to transform anything to pixel space here. That would lead to wrong coordinates once you change the limits or zoom into the plot.

However you will need to convert your dates to numbers before setting them as offsets.

```
from datetime import date

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np


x = [date(2010,5,14), date(2013,2,3), date(2014,10,9)]
y = [0.3, 0.5, 0.7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(date(2010, 1, 1), date(2015, 1, 1))
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y)

offsets = scatter.get_offsets()
new_offsets = np.array([[mdates.date2num(date(2011,3,4)), .6],[mdates.date2num(date(2012,3,4)),.7]])
new_offsets = np.append(offsets, new_offsets, axis=0)

scatter.set_offsets(new_offsets)

plt.show()
```

[image]